# Find unique values in a column of comma separated text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a column "A" that are separated by commas and I want to find all the unique values in Column A.

Here's a very short example:

```
Column A
111, 222
333
444
777,999
```

I want a query which gives me the following value:

```
Column C
111
222
333
444
777
999
```

Comment: You should fix this design - it is not relational and is the reason you are having such an issue.

Comment: This question is not clear enough.  Do you mean "I want a query which splits the value in column A by commas, trims the resulting strings, and outputs one row per value"?

Comment: IMHO. Redo the data model.  Storing comma separated lists in fields is a horrible model.  It defeats the purpose of the relational database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Comment: possible duplicate of [Irritative sql statement help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564307/irritative-sql-statement-help-needed)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the obvious problems with your table design as alluded to in all the comments and accepting that this might prove very slow on a huge table here's how I might do it.

First... I would create a statement that would turn all the rows into one big massive comma delimited list.

```
DECLARE @tmp VarChar(max)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp = @tmp + ColumnA + ',' FROM TableA
```

Then use the table valued udf split described by this SO article to turn that massive string back into a table with a distinct clause to ensure that it's unique.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837662/261997

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.Split(',', @tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [well-known Split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco) in combation with `outer apply` to split rows into multiple rows:

```
select  ltrim(rtrim(s.s)) as colC
from    @t t
cross apply
        dbo.split(',', t.colA) s
```

Full code example:

```
if object_id('dbo.Split') is not null
    drop function dbo.Split
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
go
declare @t table (colA varchar(max))
insert @t select '111, 223'
union all select '333'
union all select '444'
union all select '777,999';

select  ltrim(rtrim(s.s)) as colC
from    @t t
cross apply
        dbo.split(',', t.colA) s
```