# Distinct comma seperated value for one column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an query in SQL returns the following result:

```
Id language
1. English, French, spanish
2. English, English, spanish
3. French, French, English
```

I don't want to have duplicate value for languages, so if I have two english languages I need to display only one, so the result should be like this:

```
Id language
1. English, French, spanish
2. English, spanish
3. French, English
```

How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: is `language` a comma separated column in the table??

Comment: Can yoiu show us the table structure and the query that returns the result?

Comment: Yea it saved with comma separated in table

Comment: 1st mistake -comma separated value.2nd mistake- when value get updated ,that moment you should put validation.to avoid duplicate value.3rd mistake data redundancy i.e. db design is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191476.aspx)

```
declare @temp table (Id int,languag nvarchar(33))

insert into @temp values (1,'English, French, spanish')
insert into @temp values (2,'English, English, spanish')
insert into @temp values (3,'French, French, English')

select Id,
cast(cast('<d>'+replace(languag, ', ',',</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml).query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar) AS [language]
from @temp
```

**AFTER COMMENT**: *if i added this row : `insert into @temp values (4,'English, English, English')` the query returns to me "English, English"*

```
select Id,
REPLACE(cast(cast('<d>'+ replace(languag, ', ','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml)
.query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar), ' ', ', ')AS [language]
from @temp;
```

Comment: thanks @lad2025 you have been rocking SO from last month :) :P

Comment: There always several ways to sin a cat, however tinka's solution is elegant in that it it's almost a single liner. Anything else would almost certainly need to be at least two statements, one to parse out a comma separated string and the other to reparse it accordingly. Ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566371/find-unique-values-in-a-column-of-comma-separated-text

Comment: Thanks, if i added this row :  `insert into @temp values (4,'English, English, English')` the query returns to me **"English, English"** i need only one. and one more thing is there any way to order these values before getting the distinct ?

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working fine with sorting and getting distinct values:

```
declare @temp table (Id int,languag nvarchar(33))

insert into @temp values (1,'English, French, spanish')
insert into @temp values (2,'English, English, spanish')
insert into @temp values (3,'French, French, English')
insert into @temp values (4,'English, English, English')

select Id,
REPLACE( cast(cast('<d>'+ replace(languag, ', ','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml)
.query('for $a in distinct-values(/d) order by $a return $a') as varchar), ' ', ', ')AS [language]
from @temp
```

Thanks @tinka